# adding column with specific values

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this at the moment (although I have 2000 rows in total), and need to add another column with specific values. This is my original data so far:

| Fam | FIID |
| --- | --- |
| 1034 | 10341 |
| 1034 | 10343 |
| 1034 | 10344 |
| 1056 | 10561 |
| 1056 | 10563 |
| 1056 | 10564 |
| 1101 | 11011 |
| 1101 | 11012 |
| 1101 | 11013 |
| 1101 | 11014 |

Ultimately, I need the added column that contains the parental ID of each FIID value. But, I only need the parental ID to be filled out after the FIID ends in either a 1 or a 2. So, ultimately, I need it to look like this:

| Fam | FIID | PID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1034 | 10341 | 10343 |
| 1034 | 10343 | 0 |
| 1034 | 10344 | 0 |
| 1056 | 10561 | 10563 |
| 1056 | 10563 | 0 |
| 1056 | 10564 | 0 |
| 1101 | 11011 | 11013 |
| 1101 | 11012 | 11013 |
| 1101 | 11013 | 0 |
| 1101 | 11014 | 0 |

So, I only need the parental ID after each FIID that ends in a 1 or a 2, but there is not consistent pattern across my table, so I cannot add the parental ID with a pattern function. Any FIID that ends in a 3 or a 4 needs to receive a parental ID fo zero.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You've been asked before not to provide data as images or tables.  Please help us to help you by using `dput()`.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Where do your parental IDs [`PID`s?] come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the `PID` be retrieved by adding '3' to  `Fam` number? . If so, you can achieve your output by :

```
transform(df, PID = ifelse(grepl('1$|2$', FIID), paste0(Fam, '3'), 0))

#    Fam  FIID   PID
#1  1034 10341 10343
#2  1034 10343     0
#3  1034 10344     0
#4  1056 10561 10563
#5  1056 10563     0
#6  1056 10564     0
#7  1101 11011 11013
#8  1101 11012 11013
#9  1101 11013     0
#10 1101 11014     0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Fam = c(1034L, 1034L, 1034L, 1056L, 1056L, 1056L, 
1101L, 1101L, 1101L, 1101L), FIID = c(10341L, 10343L, 10344L, 
10561L, 10563L, 10564L, 11011L, 11012L, 11013L, 11014L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of reproducible data, here's a solution with mock data.

```
df$PID <- ifelse(grepl("(1|2)$", df$FIID), sub("(\\d+)\\d$", "\\13", df$FIID),0)
```

Result:

```
    df
  FIID  PID
1 1231 1233
2 1233    0
3 1230    0
4 1234    0
5 1232 1233
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  FIID = c(1231, 1233, 1230, 1234, 1232)
)
```